# What's the most efficient way to insert a string into an already-sorted array list of strings?

Tags: java, string, arraylist, addition

I have an ArrayList that has 17,000 words in it. I need to add a word to the list only if it's not already in and I need to preserve the sort order of the list. i.e., I need to put it into its alphabetically correct location.

I don't know how to find the correct place to insert it. 
I am using a binary search to find if the word is already in the list and that returns the index if it's in there or -1 if it's not. 
I was planning on using ArrayList.add(int index, E element) to put it in.

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: You can make a small change to the binary search to make it return either the index of the item if it is found or the index of the next item larger than it if it is not found.

Comment: These words are repeated or unique in all cases?

Comment: @trutheality shoved me in the right direction. I return the negative last searched index value if I couldn't find it. then I just insert the word at negative negative index.

Answer (score 3):

Convert the `ArrayList` into a `TreeSet` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html

The `TreeSet` will take care of duplicates for you, and keep the words in alphabetical order.

Example:  (`WordList` is the `ArrayList` of words)

```
TreeSet<String> WordSet = new TreeSet<String>(WordList);
```

Comment: +1 it is the best way for Java language to sort a List with SortedMap if you want to link a value to the String.

Comment: Thought of an addition...  if you store the list in a hashset, and only converting to TreeSet when needed to be sorted, you'll save processor time.  This is because you only sort the data once--when you convert to the TreeSet.  Otherwise, you're re-sorting every time you add an item...

Comment: +1; I was just randomly browsing, and happened to see this. You're the guy on the Arduino site, right? Small world! :P

Comment: I am! :) it is a small world indeed

Answer (score 2):

Use the built-in [`binarySearch`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) method. If the key is not found, the number returned is 
   `-(insertionIndex) - 1`

Comment: Lol, guess I was right "the list api might contain better though". This is the correct answer imo.

Comment: This is what I was trying to say with my answer, I just don't know the java API as well.  This is the best way to do this, that does not result in memory bloat of using other data structures.

Answer (score 1):

[binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) comes to mind, the list api might contain better though

In a binary search you will get to a point where you have 2 items left, one above and one below, with one of them possibly == to your item. For your case you won't have the == case, so return the index of the higher one and insert at its position. I don't know if java has a tuple class, or you can build a container. Either way, return something like:

```
(bool, int) binSearch(IList list)
  returns true, -1 if found
  returns false, higher of 2 bounds otherwise
```

obviously this isn't java but it's not a stretch to convert

Comment: I am using a binary search to find if the word is already in the list and that returns the index if it's in there or -1 if it's not.

Comment: I wanted to add a variable to the class that would be set to the closest value if the word wasn't found but due to assignment constraints (from my professor), I can't have another variable..

Comment: Pseudo code: if return == -1, set closest index value to Var. add word at Var-1.

Comment: if you can't have another variable, just have another method. Or put the code that would go in that method somewhere else if you can't add those either

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote the binary search you could modify it to return the last value searched.  This value could either be the location of the matching string or the location where it should be inserted.

That is in a binary search, you subdivide the list until you either find the string or cannot subdivide it any further.  That position where you can no longer subdivide the list is the position where your string should be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

To fasten a process, general idea comes to mind is to use more memory, as we all know. Here, it can be the indexes of the first strings for each letter. For example an additional ArrayList, writing in pseudo:

```
ArrayList indexes;
indexes[0] = {"a", 0};
indexes[1] = {"b", 123};
...
```

For a string starting with "a", you can do a binary search between the indexes 0-123.

Answer (score 0):

If there are not repeated words, as you say, you could consider implementing a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Insert operations on a trie are somewhat faster than in a hash table, that because there are no collisions. The same is true also for searching.

Moreover, in a `ArrayList` to insert an element in the middle of the list, this means reposition the half of the elements or increasing the array size, which could be somewhat expensive.

If you're curious, you can see an implementation in the following page: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=8787521